# Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter with my POJO

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create my ArrayAdapter in order to click an element in my list and get it with all the results. This is what I'm doing.

```
public ArrayAdapter<UserPojo> getAdapter(Context adapterContext) {
    return new ArrayAdapter<UserPojo>(adapterContext,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getmList());
}


public LinkedList<String> getmList() {

    mQueryDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return mList;
}
```

And here is where I use it in order to click an element and get the results of it

```
public void clickListItems(ListView listView,final DatabaseReference mRootDatabase) {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked: " + getmList().get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            userPojo = getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, UserEdit.class);
            intent.putExtra("uid", mRootDatabase.getKey());
            intent.putExtra("Name",getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position).getName());
            intent.putExtra("Email", getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position).getEmail());
            intent.putExtra("Pay", getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position).getPay());
            intent.putExtra("LastCon", getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position).getLastCon());
            intent.putExtra("FirstCon", getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position).getFirstCon();
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

The problem I'm facing is at this line

> new
>   ArrayAdapter(adapterContext,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getmList());

Saying this

> Cannot resolve constructor
>   'ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,LinkedList'

Comment: You need to create custom `ArrayAdapter` for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: did u redeclare another class with name ArrayAdapter???

Comment: because you have called method getmList() which returns mList which don't have any relation with the method. where does mList come from? you have to pass any kind of collection to your arrayadapter.

Comment: private LinkedList<String> mList = new LinkedList<>();   thats where it come from

Comment: did u use the right import for arrayadapter or another customclass called array adapter. because arrayadapter has a constructor with the methods you are calling

Comment: I have made my own and checked my imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayAdapter class needs create constructor matching super.
To create your YourAdapter:

```
YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(getActivity(), listYourPojo);
```

YourAdapter class:

```
public class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourPojo> {

    public static List<YourPojo> listYourPojo = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public YourAdapter(Context context, List<YourPojo> listYourPojo) {
        super(context, 0, listYourPojo);
        this.context = context;
        this.listYourPojo  = listYourPojo;
    }
}
```

If your List listYourPojo is static, you only need pass the index in your intent.

Comment: I did this , but when i try to add values into my List<UserPojo> i have an error in this line mList.add(userPojo.getEmail());  since getEmail is an String and the List is of type UserPojo. what I need to do ?

Comment: I cant pass mList.get(userPojo)   because is an int and mList is of type UserPojo

Comment: sorry: int index = mList.indexOf(userPojo); UserPojo userPojo = mList.get(index); userPojo.setEmail (email); mList.set(index,userPojo);

Comment: also set() is used to replace an existing value in a specific index in the list. And I need to add elements to the list not replace them

Comment: UserPojo userPojo = new UserPojo(); userPojo.setEmail(email); mList.add(userPojo);

Comment: at get(index) I get this fatal error Index: -1, Size: 0

Comment: I must be because the array is empty

Comment: Gracias santiago :)